# Users not getting updated in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am building a CRUD application using nodejs, express and mongodb. While I am trying to make REST API's I am unable to properly implement the update functionality. I don't know where and what I am missing. Can you please help me out ?

Here's my server.js

```
app.put("/api/users/:id", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: "Data to update can not be empty" });
  }

  const id = req.params.id;
  Userdb.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data) {
        res.status(404).send({
          message: `Cannot Update user with ${id}. Maybe user not found!`,
        });
      } else {
        res.send(data);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "Error Update user information" });
    });
});
```

Here's my index.js where I am sending an ajax request to server

```
$("#update_user").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var unindexed_array = $(this).serializeArray();
  var data = {};
  unindexed_array.map(function (n, i) {
    data[n["name"]] = n["value"];
  });
  console.log(data);

  var request = {
    url: `https://localhost:8080/api/users/${data.id}`,
    method: "PUT",
    data: data,
  };

  $.ajax(request).done(function (response) {
    alert("Data Updated Successfully!");
  });
})
```

And my update_user.ejs looks like this

```
<form method="POST" id="update_user">
    <div class="new_user">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="text-light">Name</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= user._id %>">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<%= user.firstandlastname %>" placeholder="Mark Stoenis">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Email" class="text-light">Pricing</label>
                <input type="text" name="pricing" value="<%= user.Pricing%>" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="text-light">Date</label>
            <input type="text" name="date" value="<%= user.Date%>" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="text-light">Pickup State</label>
            <input type="text" name="pickupstate" value="<%= user.PickupState%>" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="text-light">PickuP Location</label>
            <input type="text" name="pickupcity" value="<%= user.PickupCity%>" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="text-light">Drop State</label>
            <input type="text" name="dropstate" value="<%= user.DropState%>" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="text-light">Drop City</label>
            <input type="text" name="dropcity" value="<%= user.DropCity%>" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="text-light">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="emailid" value="<%= user.emailID%>" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="text-light">Extra Messages</label>
            <input type="text" name="exramessages" value="<%= user.extraMessages%>" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn text-dark update">Save</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What type of response do you get? Do the console.log lines fire in the server or client piece? If so, is it what you expect?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!